# WebAPI 2 OData - No routing convention for '~/entityset/key/$links/navigation'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty new to OData and WebAPI 2. Sorry ahead of time.

My goal is to use an OData service which has a `WcfService` object and a `WcfClient` object exposed, and associate the `WcfClient` with the `WcfService` through a list property `Clients`. (eg. `service.Clients.Add(client)` but using an OData service)

I have an EF code first database with `WcfService`, `WcfClient`, and `SoaApplication` classes. And, an OData webservice setup with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.1.1. The code linking everything is all setup using the wizards in VS2013. The $metadata for the OData endpoint looks like this (`http://soa.local.xxx/odata/$metadata`):

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="xxx">
      <EntityType Name="SoaApplication">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ApplicationId"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ApplicationId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="ComputerName" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="ConfigLocation" Type="Edm.String"/>
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="WcfClient">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ClientId"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ClientId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="ApplicationId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Address" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Binding" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="BindingConfiguration" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Contract" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="Application" Relationship="xxx.xxx_WcfClient_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartner" ToRole="Application" FromRole="ApplicationPartner"/>
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="WcfService">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ServiceId"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ServiceId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="ApplicationId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="AddressNoScheme" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="AddressForMatching" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Binding" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="BindingConfiguration" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Contract" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="Application" Relationship="xxx.xxx_WcfService_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartner" ToRole="Application" FromRole="ApplicationPartner"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="Clients" Relationship="xxx.xxx_WcfService_Clients_xxx_WcfClient_ClientsPartner" ToRole="Clients" FromRole="ClientsPartner"/>
      </EntityType>
      <Association Name="xxx_WcfClient_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartner">
        <End Type="xxx.SoaApplication" Role="Application" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
        <End Type="xxx.WcfClient" Role="ApplicationPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
      </Association>
      <Association Name="xxx_WcfService_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartner">
        <End Type="xxx.SoaApplication" Role="Application" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
        <End Type="xxx.WcfService" Role="ApplicationPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
      </Association>
      <Association Name="xxx_WcfService_Clients_xxx_WcfClient_ClientsPartner">
        <End Type="xxx.WcfClient" Role="Clients" Multiplicity="*"/>
        <End Type="xxx.WcfService" Role="ClientsPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
      </Association>
    </Schema>
    <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Default">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="SoaApplication" EntityType="xxx.SoaApplication"/>
        <EntitySet Name="WcfClient" EntityType="xxx.WcfClient"/>
        <EntitySet Name="WcfService" EntityType="xxx.WcfService"/>
        <AssociationSet Name="xxx_WcfClient_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartnerSet" Association="xxx.xxx_WcfClient_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartner">
          <End Role="ApplicationPartner" EntitySet="WcfClient"/>
          <End Role="Application" EntitySet="SoaApplication"/>
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="xxx_WcfService_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartnerSet" Association="xxx.xxx_WcfService_Application_xxx_SoaApplication_ApplicationPartner">
          <End Role="ApplicationPartner" EntitySet="WcfService"/>
          <End Role="Application" EntitySet="SoaApplication"/>
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="xxx_WcfService_Clients_xxx_WcfClient_ClientsPartnerSet" Association="xxx.xxx_WcfService_Clients_xxx_WcfClient_ClientsPartner">
          <End Role="ClientsPartner" EntitySet="WcfService"/>
          <End Role="Clients" EntitySet="WcfClient"/>
        </AssociationSet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

The `WcfService` class has a property, `List<WcfClient> Clients`, which I would like to populate with a list of clients associated with the `WcfService`.

The `WcfService` class looks kinda like this:

```
[DataServiceKey("ServiceId")]
public class WcfService
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    ... snip ...

    public List<WcfClient> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

The code I have for add the relationship between the object looks like this:

```
   var ctx = new Container(uri);
   var service = ctx.WcfServices.Expand("Clients".Where(i => i.ServiceId == 21).ToArray()[0];
   var client = ctx.WcfClients.Where(i => i.ClientId == 220).ToArray()[0];
   ctx.AddLink(service, "Clients", client);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Unfortunately, an error occurs. This is the full request and response (edited for namespaces) that are sent across the wire (from fiddler)

Request:

```
POST http://soa.local.xxx/odata/WcfService(21)/$links/Clients HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/xml
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Host: soa.local.xxx
Content-Length: 174
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uri xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">http://soa.local.xxx/odata/WcfClient(220)</uri>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 15 Mar 2014 23:50:12 GMT
Content-Length: 565

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <m:code />
  <m:message xml:lang="en-US">No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://soa.local.xxx/odata/WcfService(21)/$links/Clients'.</m:message>
  <m:innererror>
    <m:message>No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/$links/navigation'.</m:message>
    <m:type></m:type>
    <m:stacktrace></m:stacktrace>
  </m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

I don't understand why the format of the request url is `'~/entityset(key)/$links/navigation'` and the error message says `'~/entityset/key/$links/navigation'`?

It looks like the format used in the url was listed as supported in [WCF Data Service 4.5](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions). But, I'm probably looking in the wrong area for a solution.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm applying the change? Is there a more appropriate way to write the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like I needed to read the documentation more thoroughly. In [Working with Entity Relations](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/working-with-entity-relations) there are `CreateLink` and `DeleteLink` example methods. Once those methods were added to the Controller the calls started going through successfully.

I guess the routing convention is setup; but the error message occured because there were no methods to map the conventions to.